# how to show the result query columnar instead of row by row?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have three tables:

```
Flight table
 FlightId  int
 FlightNumber varchar(10)

FlightCapacity table
ID int
FlightIdRef int
ClassIdRef  int
Capacity    int

Class Table
ClassId  int
Name      varchar(10)

Class Table:
ClassId     Name
   1         Y
   2         A

Flight Table
FlightId   Number
1           123
2           423

FlightCapacity Table
Id   FlightIdRef    ClassIdref  Capacity
1       1              1          10
2       1              2          20
3       2              2          10
```

this is a simple query:

```
select Flight.FlightNumber,Class.Name+RTRIM(FlightCapacity.Capacity)
   from  Flight
      inner join FlightCapacity
           on Flight.FlightId=FlightCapacity.FlightIdRef
               inner join Class
                    on FlightCapacity.ClassIdRef=Class.ClassId
```

but I want following result:(I want to show all classes of every flight and capacity in one single row)

```
FlightNumber     ClassNameAndCapacity
  123                 Y10  A20
  423                 Y10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
;WITH x(fn,cn) AS 
(
   SELECT f.FlightNumber, c.Name + RTRIM(fc.Capacity)
   FROM dbo.Flight AS f
   INNER JOIN dbo.FlightCapacity AS fc
   ON f.FlightId = fc.FlightIdRef
   INNER JOIN dbo.Class AS c
   ON fc.ClassIdRef = c.ClassId
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    FlightNumber = fn, 
    ClassNameAndCapacity = (SELECT cn + ' ' 
      FROM x AS x2 
      WHERE x2.fn = x.fn 
      FOR XML PATH('')
    )
FROM x
ORDER BY FlightNumber;
```

Comment: could you explain me the second part.

Comment: `FOR XML PATH` is a trick used to aggregate values. So for each FlightNumber it takes all of the c.Name + fc.Capacity values, adds a space, and munges them together.

Comment: Sorry guy. my problem a little has been changed. could you see this post? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460531/how-to-show-query-result-columnarin-different-columns-instead-of-row-by-row)